# Excel "spill range is unknown" with limited possible range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having some trouble figuring out why I'm frequently getting spill errors.  Here's the deal:  I have column C with exactly 200 elements that take the form "x -- y" where x and y are positive integers each generated by the RANDBETWEEN function.  Then in cell D2 I use the UNIQUE function create a spilled array out of the column C contents.  But about 60% of the time I get a SPILL error, "Spill range is unknown".  I get that there is some variability in the length of the array, but it can't ever be over 200.  It doesn't make sense to me that this error would occur when there is a strict upper limit.  FWIW, the UNIQUE formula is:

=UNIQUE(C2:C200)

I could see that there might be a problem with C:C instead of C2:200, but not with the way this is set up.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the function used in C:C so we can reproduce?

Comment: It's due to the use of `RANDBETWEEN`. See Section 3 - *Spill Range is Undetermined* - in this link: https://exceltrick.com/how_to/spill-error-excel/

Comment: If you random number sequences doesn't need to be updated too often, you could use the excel built-in 'Data Analysis' Add-in to generate the 2 random variable outputs and thereby avoid the problem of using `RAND...` functions. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shl2y.png).